# How to fix when I passed an id in the edit button and clicked then suddenly every file path was changed and the function is coming in every path file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I add an id and pass it after the route (showBranch) means method. When I clicked on the edit button, the view is reloaded and the whole theme is disturbed. The path changed for every file and gave me a 404 error.

```
<a data-toggle='modal' class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="mybar" name="mybar" href="<?= base_url() . 'showBranch/' . $br_data->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
```

Comment: Looks like some file is not properly closed. Most likely a template file.

Comment: The below is the code i  make route for this also but when click on it in every file path showBranch is comming which make 404 error for all theme file <a data-toggle='modal' class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="mybar" name="mybar" href="<?= base_url().'showBranch/'.$br_data->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete </a>

Comment: Did you try to remove the shorthand echo? (And make a proper `echo` instead)

Comment: @paskl yes i did that but wasn't fixed